# Can we create custom fields on Organization and User Objects?

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects

Is it possible to create custom fields on the `Organization` and `User` objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom fields on the `User` object:

```
Setup -> Customize -> Users -> Fields -> New User Custom Field
```

but you can't create custom fields on the `Organization` object.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `user` object falls in the same category as `Organization`

Comment: Please select that as a correct answer, if your question is rightly answered so that the question can be closed. @javanoob